# Keep indentation when including template with FreeMarker

Tags: freemarker

When I include a template with `<#include ...>` directive, the content of that template is inserted starting from column 0 and not where the `include` tag was located. Is it possible to tell FreeMarker to respect indentation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use macros and pass them the indentation as a parameter. Consider, for example, building a list of courses in  YAML format, where each one has a list of students.

report.ftl:

```
<#include "course.ftl" parse=true>
<#include "faculty.ftl" parse=true>
<#include "student.ftl" parse=true>
<#list report as course>
    <@newCourse course = course indent = 0/>
</#list>
```

course.ftl:

```
<#include "faculty.ftl" parse=true>
<#include "student.ftl" parse=true>
<#macro newCourse course indent>
    <#local padding = ""?left_pad(4*indent)/>
${padding}course:
${padding}    code: ${course.code}
${padding}    name: ${course.name}
              <@newFaculty code = "${course.faculty.code}" name = "${course.faculty.name}" indent =  indent + 1/>
${padding}    students:
                  <#list course.students as student>
                      <@newStudent code = "${student.code}" name = "${student.name}" indent =  indent + 2/>
                  </#list>
</#macro>
```

faculty.ftl:

```
<#macro newFaculty code name indent>
    <#local padding = ""?left_pad(4*indent)/>
${padding}faculty:
${padding}    code: ${code}
${padding}    name: ${name}
</#macro>
```

student.ftl:

```
<#macro newStudent code name indent>
    <#local padding = ""?left_pad(4*indent)/>
${padding}- student:
${padding}    code: ${code}
${padding}    name: ${name}
</#macro>
```

pojos:

```
class Course {
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private Faculty faculty;
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Faculty {
    private String code;
    private String name;
}

class Student {
    private String code;
    private String name;  
}
```